# Eigen download ssl certificate verify failed

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, python3

I am trying to install the finite element software Firedrake, but I'm getting the following error message:

```
...

Failed to clone loopy using ssh, falling back to https.
Successfully cloned repository loopy.
Checking out branch firedrake
Successfully checked out branch firedrake
Installing petsc/
Downloading Eigen from 'https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/3.3.3.tar.gz' to 'eigen-3.3.3.tgz'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1317, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1392, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 853, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1117, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "firedrake-install", line 1196, in <module>
    install("petsc/")
  File "firedrake-install", line 670, in install
    build_and_install_petsc()
  File "firedrake-install", line 756, in build_and_install_petsc
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename=tarball)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1360, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1319, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)>
```

I've already installed certifi using pip, and I get the same error message when I run, e.g.,

`python3 -c 'import certifi; import urllib.request; urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/3.3.3.tar.gz")'.`

I'd appreciate any insight than anyone might have.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this Python bug issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue36137).

Comment: @Anaksunaman Hmm it looks like that bug is specific to windows.. I am using Mac OSX